# Detect end of forEach loop that contains http requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this function and inside `forEach` loop that iterate trough items... What I want to achieve is to to render some spinner ( loader ) until all of `http` requests are done, until `forEach` loop is done.

The way I am trying now, first and last `console.log` triggers immediately and then it logs second `console.log` as many times as there are items in the items array.

How can I update state to `loading: false` when `forEach` iteration is done, when all `http` requests are done?

```
someHandler = () => {
    // this.setState({ loading: false })
       console.log( "Not loading" )
    this.props.items.forEach(item => {
      axios
        .get(`.../${item}/`)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            item: [
              ...prevState.item,
              {
                name: res.data.name,
                img: res.data.img
              }
            ]
          }));
          this.props.newItem(this.state.item);
          // this.setState({ loading: true })
             console.log( "Loading" )
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          // this.setState({ loading: false })
             console.log( "Not loading" )
        });
    });
    // this.setState({ loading: false })
       console.log( "Not loading" )
  };
```

Comment: You could add the index to the `forEach`: `this.props.items.forEach((item, index) => ` and then add `if (index===this.props.items.length) this.setState({ loading: false });`

Comment: I did this like you said `if (index + 1  === this.props.items.length)` because index is 5 and the length of array is 6, but that still sets my state before all http req are done...

Comment: Ofc, you are correct. The asynchronous nature of course also means you have no clue in what order the promises will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async/await` with `for...of`

You can assume sequential execution with this approach.

```
someHandler = async () => {
  console.log('Not loading'); // will execute before loop
  this.setState({ loading: true }); // start loading

  for (let item of this.props.items) {
    const res = await axios.get(`.../${item}/`);
    // ... do your logic with response
    console.log('Loading');
  }

  console.log('Not loading'); // will execute after loop
  this.setState({ loading: false }); // end loading
};
```

Comment: Thank you Dinesh! That's it! I still have a lot to learn about async code. Thanks again! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use async/await in your env, and want to wait until a number of promises are resolved, then `Promise.all` is your friend. I may have missed something, but in a nutshell, you could rewrite your function to be like this:

```
const requests = this.props.items.map(item => (
  axios.get(`...${item}`).then(res => {
    const newItem = { name: res.data.name, img: res.data.img }
    this.props.newItem(newItem)
    return newItem
  })
))

Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
  this.setState({ item: responses })
})
```

This creates a new array of promises called `requests` and when they're all done, uses `setState` to set all the responses.